# Sync Files from folder to another using windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

I was trying to sync files from folder to another automatically,
I managed to do this using windows 10 task scheduler ,
I used a PowerShell code given by someone, then I run it every 5 min,
I wonder if there is any other way to make the task runs every time a file is added to the source folder to avoid running the task every 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is. you can use the `FileSystemWatcher`. a sample script can be found in the technet gallery: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b